# Not able to run npm run dev in laravel

Tags: laravel

When using npm run dev to compile tailwind file, i am having this error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Can't resolve 'assets/overview_back.jpg'
```

my code in that tailwind file is:

```
 <section class="h-25 w-full bg-[url('assets/overview_back.jpg')]">
```

Where can i put external images or logos in for tailwind in laravel?

Comment: it's `{{` and `}}` and not `[` `]` please use correct braces in your code and it'll resolve.

Comment: @HassaanAli i tried, but can not do. what's wrong in my code? 
  <section class="h-25 w-full bg-{{  url('assets/overview_back.jpg')}}">

Comment: What's the file structure inside your assets ? Is it inside your public domain ? or is it in storage ?